# Multi threading in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, afnetworking

I have a doubt regarding multi threading in iOS objective C. I have never worked on threads.. 
In my app, I have a couple of tasks that need to run only in background so that the UI doesn't get freezed. 
Following is the code snippet,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            [self someFunctionCallinWebservice];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //UI Updates
            });
        });
```

In the above code, function : someFunctionCallinWebservice calls webservice for which I am using AFNetworking library. In the webservice if it is a success then I am saving the data locally. I am calling a function in success block to save the data sent from server like below,

```
[manager POST:url parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
[self functionToSaveData:someArray];
}
```

Here the someFunctionCallinWebservice is running in background but `[self functionToSaveData:someArray]` runs in foreground. Should I have this functionToSaveData also in background thread?

I mean if I am calling a function in background then all related functionalities of that function like, calling server, getting the data and saving it must also fall in background thread right? Why should I create another thread again?

Please help...

Comment: It can all run in the background *until* you need to interact with the UI classes in any way.  So fetch and save in the background and then nudge the UI to update when complete.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, u can call functionToSaveData function in **background** thread it will not create any issue but if u want to do any UI updates (like :-> reload tableView, show or hide some views) at that time u must do it on main thread otherwise it will not do any effect on your UI.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    //Do any UI updates here 
});
```

**Edit:** Swift 4

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
         //Do any UI updates here   
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Multi-threading is a large and difficult subject, for which iOS has different types of supports. I suggest you read Apple's [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html) to start with.

For the type of action that you seem to be doing (fetching data from the internet), I suggest you use the iOS asynchronous APIs, such as [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:), which remove the need to do anything with multi-threading yourself.

The answer to your concrete question depends on whether your `POST:parameters:success:` operation is a synchronous or an asynchronous operation, and it depends on what the `functionToSaveData:` actually does. 
Assuming that `functionToSaveData:` is intended to share the data with the rest of your app, it would be best to do it on the main thread, to avoid synchronisation problems.